# Memory leak, while allocating a two dimensional game field

Tags: c

I am new to using Valgrind and have problems debugging the code, since it works except for what I assume are memory leaks on the marked line. Am I allocating the wrong size here?

```
Field *createField(unsigned int xsize, unsigned int ysize) {
    /* Alright! Let's start off by assigning an new field that we can return.*/

unsigned int i, j;
    Field *returnField;
    returnField = malloc(sizeof(Field));
    if(returnField == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    returnField->xsize = xsize;
    returnField->ysize = ysize;
    returnField->cells = malloc(ysize * sizeof(State *)); // memory leaks?!
    if(returnField->cells == NULL) {
        free(returnField);
        return NULL;
    }
    /* Alright, now we have the y dimension pointer allocated. It's time
     * to move on to the x dimension*/

    for (j = 0; j < ysize; j++) {
        returnField->cells[j] = malloc(xsize * sizeof(State));
        if (returnField->cells[j] == NULL) {
            for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                free(returnField->cells[i]);
            }
            free(returnField);
            return NULL;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < xsize; i++) {
            returnField->cells[j][i] = DEAD;
        }
    }

    return returnField; 
}
/* Free memory allocated for field <f>.
 */
void releaseField(Field *f)
{
    unsigned int j;
    for (j = 0; j < f->ysize; j++) {

        free(f->cells[j]);
    }
    free(f);
}
```

Below is the header containing the structures:

```
typedef enum {
    DEAD,
    ALIVE
} State;

typedef struct {
    unsigned int xsize, ysize;
    State **cells;
} Field;
```

Comment: Where is line 24? `returnField->cells[j][i] = DEAD;` accesses already freed memory.

Comment: Please add the code where you are deallocating memory.

Comment: "Memory leaks" don't occur when you allocate memory, they occur when you fail to deallocate it. Valgrind is pointing you to where you allocate the memory that's leaking, but the problem is unlikely to be on that line. Instead, the problem will be where you either fail to deallocate it, or where you later lose your reference to that memory and it becomes inaccessible.

Answer (score 3):

You allocate memory to hold the cell pointers:

```
returnField->cells = malloc(ysize * sizeof(State *));
```

But you never free that memory. You do free the individual cells, but never the cell pointer itself:

```
    if (returnField->cells[j] == NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            free(returnField->cells[i]);
        }
        free(returnField->cells);
        // ^^ This was missing
        free(returnField);
        return NULL;
    }
```

The same problem appears in your `releaseField()` implementation. I'd even suggest making it *robust* against partial allocation:

```
/* Free memory allocated for field <f>.
 */
void releaseField(Field *f)
{
    unsigned int j;
    if (f != NULL) {
       if (f->cells != NULL) {
           for (j = 0; j < f->ysize; j++) {
               free(f->cells[j]);
           }
       }
       // free cell pointer array memory, too
       free(f->cells);
       free(f);
    }
}
```

Also replace `returnField->cells = malloc(ysize * sizeof(State *));` by

```
returnField->cells = calloc(ysize, sizeof(State *));
```

Do the same thing when allocating the `returnField` struct itself and you can even use `releaseField()` for partially allocated fields and thus avoid code duplication:

```
returnField = calloc(1, sizeof(Field));
```

This way, you should be able to simply call `releaseField()` even when you only have a partially allocacted field structure.

Comment: added the line, but I still get the same Valgrind complaints.. Could the problem be in releaseField() function?

Comment: Actually, I would even suggest making `releaseField()` robust against partial allocation. `free(NULL)` is specified to be a nop. If you use `returnField->cells = calloc(ysize, sizeof(State *))` you get `cells` zeroed. You could then simply call `releaseField()` when a partial allocation fails and avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the real problem but you are not deallocating the memory allocated for `cells` in this block.

```
    if (returnField->cells[j] == NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            free(returnField->cells[i]);
        }

        // Need to deallocate returnField->cells
        // Add the following line.
        free(returnField->cells);

        free(returnField);
        return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: Valgrind rightfully complains about this as a memory leak. It happens only when running out of memory during the allocation, though.